# Want to convert text file of complex numbers to a list of numbers in Python

Tags: python, string, file, complex-numbers

I have a text file of complex numbers called `output.txt` in the form:

```
[-3.74483279909056 + 2.54872970226369*I]
[-3.64042002652517 + 0.733996349939531*I]
[-3.50037473491252 + 2.83784532111642*I]
[-3.80592861109028 + 3.50296053533826*I]
[-4.90750592116062 + 1.24920836601026*I]
[-3.82560512449716 + 1.34414866823615*I]
etc...
```

I want to create a list from these (read in as a string in Python) of complex numbers.

Here is my code:

```
data = [line.strip() for line in open("output.txt", 'r')]
for i in data:
    m = map(complex,i)
```

However, I'm getting the error:

```
ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the help information, for the `complex` builtin function:

```
>>> help(complex)
class complex(object)
 |  complex(real[, imag]) -> complex number
 |
 |  Create a complex number from a real part and an optional imaginary part.
 |  This is equivalent to (real + imag*1j) where imag defaults to 0.
```

So you need to format the string properly, and pass the real and imaginary parts as separate arguments.

---

Example:

```
num = "[-3.74483279909056 + 2.54872970226369*I]".translate(None, '[]*I').split(None, 1)
real, im = num
print real, im
>>> -3.74483279909056 + 2.54872970226369
im = im.replace(" ", "") # remove whitespace
c = complex(float(real), float(im))
print c
>>> (-3.74483279909+2.54872970226j)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however, I keep getting a new error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: [-3.74483279909056   why couldn't it do that?

Comment: @AIREL You can't have the opening bracket `[` for that number. Are you sure you are running `.translate(None, '[]*I')` which removes the `[]*I` characters?

Comment: You're correct, sorry about that.  Now I just have to get past the hurdle of the complex numbers having both Re +Im and Re -Im.  .split won't understand an or function will it...

Comment: @AIREL The 1 argument to `.split` means it is only splits it into two strings: the real part, and everything else. Thus, `im` has the sign in it, and `float` will know to take that into account. So this should work for both Re +Im and Re -Im. I'd recommend adding `print` statements to see the values of intermediate variables, to convince yourself it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
numbers = []
with open("output.txt", 'r') as data:
    for line in data.splitlines():
        parts = line.split('+')
        real, imag = tuple( parts[0].strip(' ['), parts[1].strip(' *I]') )
        numbers.append(complex(float(real), float(imag)))
```

The problem with your original approach is that your input file contains lines of text that complex() does not know how to process.  We first need to break each line down to a pair of numbers - real and imag.  To do that, we need to do a little string manipulation (split and strip).  Finally, we convert the real and imag strings to floats as we pass them into the complex() function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concise way to create the list of complex values (based on dal102 answer):

```
data = [complex(*map(float,line.translate(None, ' []*I').split('+'))) for line in open("output.txt")]
```